# Searching dates in mm/yyyy format

Tags: python, regex, date

I have dates in `mm/dd/yyyy` format as well as `mm/yyyy` formats in my text file. How do I search dates which are `mm/yyyy` without showing the results from `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

I have following 2 scenarios

1. line starting with `mm/yyyy` - `'^\d{1,2}/\d{4}'` (No problem here)
2. Problem arises when date in the middle or end of the line. I have
   dates with special characters and alphabets before them. So dates
   such as `~09/2009` are also required but get rejected if I search as 
   `' \d{1,2}/\d{4}'`.

   To avoid this
   I need an expression such that the date `mm/yyyy` doesn't follow a forward
   slash. but for some reason `'[^/]\d{1,2}/\d{4}'` isn't working. It
   shows dates like `01/03/2010` as `03/2010`.

Here's a snippet from ipython

```
import re
text1 = 'Appointment is on 10/06/2009. Next appointment in 07/2009'
re.findall('[^\/](\d{1,2}/\d{4})',text1)
```

Out: ['6/2009', '07/2009']

Krishna

Comment: Add some example input snippets and your output from those.

Comment: if escape slash `[^\/]` ?

Comment: In: import re
     text1 = 'Appointment is on 10/06/2009. Next appointment in 07/2009'
     re.findall('[^/](\d{1,2}/\d{4})',text1)

Out: ['6/2009', '07/2009']

The first date shown in the list is unwanted.

Comment: Please [edit] these in to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your month/year string must not have preceding slash or digit

```
(?<!\/|\d)\d{1,2}/\d{4}
```

In your expression, because you allow one digit, it selects the first digit 0 (as not slash) and the rest of string 0`6/2009` - that matches the patern `[^/](\d{1,2}/\d{4}`

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/fqB8Na/1)